# How do I emulate Internet Explorer url encoding in a console app

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, encoding

The objective:

Make a console app that send a simple get request - in exactly the right way.

The problem:

I have a url like this:
`http://myhost/somepage.do?Search01=コード番号=123456&Search02=改訂番号=2`

When I copy and past this into IE 11 or lower, the page I want returns correctly.
When I copy and past this into IE Edge, chrome, firefox, it returns an error saying it does not properly recognize the parameters.

I investigated this with Wireshark, and I can see quite clearly that ol' IE is sending the url with some kind of different encoding:
[image]

Whereas Chrome does a more expected encoding:
[image]

I don't fully understand what is happening here, but it seems that this server I am sending the message to, is somewhat TAILORED towards ol' IE's messed up way of encoding the url - because it is only replying to the messed up requests.

I have checked other things like the useragent etc - it makes no difference. This server is running a service which is very old (maybe using ASP).

So, my objective is to emulate this messed up encoding in a console app. How do I do it?

Comment: FYI, copy pasting the correctly encoded version of the url (copied from chrome) does NOT work in IE. It seems the server specifically wants the messed up encoding version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, with some help from understanding what might be happening via:
[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18220057/encoding-of-query-string-parameters-in-ie10/18220123#18220123)

I came to realize how my url is being encoded.

My computer is Japanese, so the default codepage is 932.
After much messing around with a sample console app, and watching the packets in Wireshark, I realized that no matter what I did, the default **`HttpClient` and `WebClient` will always UrlEncode my URL correctly** regardless of what encoding I used. This is not how ol' IE encodes it's URLs.

I dug deeper and found that [in the source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs) for `HttpClient` (and `WebClient`) it uses the class [`Uri`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Private.Uri/src/System/Uri.cs), which has a constructor with parameter : `DontEscape` which I thought, "Eurika!" but it turns out this constructor is Obsolete, and **there is no way to not make URL's automatically escape themselves when using `HttpClient` or `WebClient`**.

So I had to use `TcpClient` and make my own request instead. Which [I stole from here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523088/create-http-request-using-tcpclient?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The initial request to search only works if the url is encoded using Shift-JIS, which means we cannot use any client library and must use a custom TCP message.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serveripaddress"></param>
    /// <param name="restoftheurl"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task<string> HttpRequestAsync(string serveripaddress, string restoftheurl)
    {
        Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
        string result = string.Empty;

        using (var tcp = new TcpClient(serveripaddress, 80))
        using (var stream = tcp.GetStream())
        {
            tcp.SendTimeout = 500;
            tcp.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
            Console.WriteLine("URL rest:" + restoftheurl);
            // Send request headers
            var builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.AppendLine("GET " + restoftheurl + " HTTP/1.1");
            builder.AppendLine("Host: " + serveripaddress);
            //builder.AppendLine("Content-Length: " + data.Length);   // only for POST request
            builder.AppendLine("Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*");
            builder.AppendLine("Accept-Language: ja-JP");
            builder.AppendLine("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko");
            builder.AppendLine("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate");
            builder.AppendLine("Connection: Close");
            builder.AppendLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Sending message:" + builder.ToString());
            var header = Encoding.GetEncoding(932).GetBytes(builder.ToString());
            await stream.WriteAsync(header, 0, header.Length);

            // Send payload data if you are POST request
            //await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);

            // receive data
            using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
                memory.Position = 0;
                var data = memory.ToArray();

                var index = BinaryMatch(data, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n\r\n")) + 4;
                var headers = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, index);
                memory.Position = index;

                if (headers.IndexOf("Content-Encoding: gzip") > 0)
                {
                    using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(memory, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                    using (var decompressedMemory = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedMemory);
                        decompressedMemory.Position = 0;
                        result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressedMemory.ToArray());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, index, data.Length - index);
                    //result = Encoding.GetEncoding("gbk").GetString(data, index, data.Length - index);
                }
            }

            //Debug.WriteLine(result);
            return result;
        }
    }

    private int BinaryMatch(byte[] input, byte[] pattern)
    {
        int sLen = input.Length - pattern.Length + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < sLen; ++i)
        {
            bool match = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < pattern.Length; ++j)
            {
                if (input[i + j] != pattern[j])
                {
                    match = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (match)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

The key part of this code is:

**`var header = Encoding.GetEncoding(932).GetBytes(builder.ToString());`**

This forces the string to be encoded in my codepage, which required that the codepage provider was registered, so at the top: 
`Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);`

The usage is simple:

`await HttpRequestAsync("123.456.789.123", "/somepage.do?Search01=コード番号=123456&Search02=改訂番号=2");`